# Is there a way to detect a new user joining a discord server when logged in via Discord.JS as a user account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am wondering if there is a way to detect a new user joining a discord server when logged in via Discord.JS as a user account?

I tried guildmemberadd listener but that only appears to work for Bot accounts.

Comment: guildMemberAdd is a privileged intent. I don't think this is possible, because I don't think user accounts can be assigned that right.

Comment: Okay thank you. If they have something like "Invite Tracker" installed and whenever a new user joins the server it prints out their discord username in a channel could you take that username and then find their ID and then send them a message?

Comment: Yeah, it might be a little tricky but you could  set it up so that a bot notified the user, and then the user account sent the message.